# "Couldn't find" Error ActiveRecord.new method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I facing this problem in may Rails 3.0.3 App, I think this is a silly error but I can't figure out why it's happening, or in fact, I'm misunderstanding the ActiveRecord behavior and it's is not really a error.

This is the scenario, I've three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base  
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable  
    has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable  
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses  
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true  
  belongs_to :address_base  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address_base  
end  

class AddressBase < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :address  
end
```

If I try to instantiate a new User passing a hash parameters, by this way:

```
User.new({"addresses_attributes"=>  
    {"0"=>
        {"number"=>"10",
         "complement"=>"Next Starbucks",
         "address_base_attributes"=>
            {"city"=>"San Francisco",
             "zip_code"=>"00010",
             "district"=>"San Francisco",
             "id"=>"10",
             "street"=>"Market St.",
             "state"=>"CA"}
        }
    },
    "name"=>"Homer Simpson",
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "document"=>"123321111",
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
    "email"=>"homer@simpson.com"
})
```

I face the error

```
Couldn't find AddressBase with ID=10 for Address with ID=
```

And it happens because that AddressBase already exists and the Address don't, if I remove the AddressBase.id parameter of the hash everything works, but I not want it, because on this way, always will be created a new register for Address and AddressBase. My intention is reuse commons AddressBase's, so the scenario of a new Address with an existent AddressBase will be necessary.

Now this is my doubts, I'm missing some parameter in the AddressBase hash?? Something like saying that the record already exist? Or it's a problem with belongs_to and has_many associations of ActiveRecord?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot mass assign the ID attribute in rails models (give the ID to the data hash you initialize the model with).

It's hard for me to reproduce you're situation but if you know the model exist it's easier to supply the id of address_base instead of a hash with all the data.

For example:

```
User.new({"addresses_attributes"=>  
  {"0"=>
      {"number"=>"10",
       "complement"=>"Next Starbucks",
       "address_base_id" => 10}
  },
  "name"=>"Homer Simpson",
  "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "document"=>"123321111",
  "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "email"=>"homer@simpson.com"
```

})

Comment: Thanks @danny-hiemstra! It that you suggest is what I could not really to see. I just need to think now how I will build the views to accomplish this situation, because the problem has scenarios, one is when the AddressBase already exist, so I will just pass the address_base_id in the hash, the second scenario is when the AddressBase don't exists, so he will need be created and I will need to pass all he's values in the hash, I will try to figure out how to do this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Also what you might want to do is first check if it exists, if it does remove the key from the params hash with for example the Hash.delete method and then add a new value to the hash with the address_base_id.

Comment: I'm doing a checking in my controller, I'm nothing passing anymore the 'id' in the hash, and in the controller I check if an AddressBase already exists with the given zip_code in the database, if true I just set the reference directly `user.addresses.first.address_base = address_base_from_database` (it's is just a snippet), if false I just save the user and the address and address_base are created. But what I want is solve this directly in the view. Why rails when the hash has the `id` of AddressBase he's try to look in for a register of Address, this is a common behavior of belongs_to?